# django model structure (database structure)

Tags: python-3.x, django, database

I have one model many to one current state of this as follows:

```
class A(models.Model):
   a_field = models.CharField()

class B(models.Model):
   c_field = models.CharField()

class C(models.Model):
   c_field = models.CharField()
```

and they are related to D model

```
class D(models.Model):
   a_field = models.ForeignKey(A)
   b_field = models.ForeignKey(B)
   c_field = models.ForeignKey(C)
```

here there may be more related fields to the `D` model

my questions are that is it a good database structure?

or should I just do this

```
class D(models.Model)
   object_id = models.IntegerField()
```

in here there will be no related fields I will just save the ID

can anybody answer to this question please?

Comment: Question - at a time, will you have all the keys a,b,c in model D or at a time there will be only one and other fields will be Null?

Comment: This is what relational databases are *for*. Maintaining relationships between entities in tables of data. They are good at it.  Just make sure you design your tables to suit your problem. (It's a bit like DRY in programming). You can read about the various levels of "normalisation" (Nth Normal form) and the cons (and sometimes pros) of denormalisation if you need further guidance.

Comment: @Zilay yes they will be nullable

Comment: Then I prefer you to use polymorphic relationship using content type